# Webpack Dev Server 2.1.0-beta.02 fails to load modules on second compilation

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I’m setting up a new project with `webpack2.1.0-beta.22` and `web-pack-dev-server2.1.0-beta.2`.

Now, I’ve set up a webpack build configs a few times so I’m not a stranger to the process, however I seem to have a weird bug. when I run `webpack` straight up, my app compiles with 0 problems. But, when I run `webpack-dev-server` it fails after the first compilation (IE. after first source code change) complaining about not being able to find certain files.

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./src/app.css
Module build failed: (SystemJS) ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jamie/skyrkt/bento-components/node_modules/css-loader/lib/loader'
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jamie/skyrkt/bento-components/node_modules/css-loader/lib/loader'
        at Error (native)
    Error loading /Users/jamie/skyrkt/bento-components/node_modules/css-loader/lib/loader as "./lib/loader" from /Users/jamie/skyrkt/bento-components/node_modules/css-loader/index.js
 @ ./src/app.css 4:14-116
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi main
```

And sometimes this error, depending on if I update CSS or JS.

```
 ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed: (SystemJS) ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jamie/skyrkt/bento-components/object-assign'
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jamie/skyrkt/bento-components/object-assign'
        at Error (native)
    Error loading /Users/jamie/skyrkt/bento-components/object-assign as "object-assign" from /Users/jamie/skyrkt/bento-components/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js
 @ multi main
```

My whole webpack config is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports =  {
  entry: {
    main: path.join(__dirname,'src/index.js')
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname,'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new htmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname,'src/index.html')
    })
  ],
  postcss: function(webpack) {
    // Irrelevant PostCSS things.
  },
  devServer: {
    port: '8080',
    host: 'localhost',
    inline: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000
    },
    outputPath: path.join(__dirname,'dist')
  }
}
```

The command that I am running is

`webpack-dev-server --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/`

It looks like the dev server thinks it’s running relative to root or something? I’m not 100% sure.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I can confirm that this does not happen when using `webpack@1.13.2` and `webpack-dev-server@1.15.1` and instead of using `import` in my code, using `require`.

Thanks,
Jamie